# Make a "fork" of a depot repo in perforce

Tags: perforce

In perforce I have a repository in `depot`. I want to make a copy of this repo under `tasks` or `streams`. Speaking with git terminology - to make a fork. How can I make it? I have a write-access to a repo in `depot`.

Since I might confuse perforce terms, I will show with screenshot examples:
Under `depot` I have several folders like this:

[image]

I want to copy one of the folders under `depot` and paste it under `streams` as shown on here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll give two different answers, neither of which uses the word "repo" or "fork" since those aren't terms in Perforce and they could mean two different things ("repo" could be a "depot" or a "server" -- the confusion is compounded by the fact that people sometimes say "depot" to mean "server" if their server only has one depot):

To **branch** a **path** `//depot/thing` from your **classic depot** `depot` into a new **stream** on the same **server**:

1. Create a new **stream depot**: `p4 depot -t stream streams`
2. Create a new **stream**: `p4 stream //streams/thing`
3. **Populate** the **stream** from `//depot`: `p4 populate //depot/thing/... //streams/thing/...`

To **clone** that **path** from your **shared server** into a **mainline stream** on a new **personal server**:

1. `p4 clone -f //depot/thing/...`

(The `p4 clone` command automatically creates a **stream depot**, a **mainline stream**, and a **client workspace** on your **personal server** that will be created in the current working directory -- you should run this someplace outside of the **client workspace** that you use on the **shared server**.)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! I only worked with Perforce through a `p4v` visual client. When using a CLI - where on a filesystem should I be located to run these commands?

Comment: For the `p4 clone` you should be in the directory where you want to create your new personal server (*not* in the workspace you use on the shared server).

The first scenario (where you're branching on the shared server rather than cloning into a personal server) doesn't do anything with the local filesystem so it doesn't matter where you are locally as long as you're connected to the right server.  Note that once you've made your new stream you'll probably want to create a new stream workspace with a different Root from your classic workspace (you can do this from P4V just fine).

Comment: With current changes and visual examples I've just added to a question, do I understand correctly that your first example will do exactly what I want?

Comment: Ah, I guessed two possible interpretations for what you meant by "repo" and it was neither of them!  What you're talking about is a **path** that is a subset of a **depot** which is itself a subset of a **server** (which is usually what Git people call a **repo** since it's the absolute top-level unit of stuff in Perforce).  Updated answer.

Comment: I could probably give you better answers if I knew more about your depot structure -- I have no idea how different branches fit into any of this, and as far as I can tell you aren't otherwise doing branching at all, so my answer is given with that assumption.  If your path has multiple subpaths that each represent a branch, you would want to map one branch to one stream, **NOT** put all the branches into a single stream.

Comment: Yes, each of the paths shown on a screenshot has multiple sub-paths underneath and so on. But if we would consider that those that are in a pic - are finite, what would be my first step in "forking" it in a new stream?

Comment: See answer.  You didn't answer my question about whether they're branches so I unfortunately can't give you anything any more helpful.  :(  Seeing the actual path names would allow me to make a guess (like if your subpaths were "src" and "lib" my answer would be different from if they were "rel1.0" and "rel1.1" since those names represent different concepts that map differently into Perforce streams), but seeing the first couple of letters doesn't give me a lot of clues..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168466/discussion-between-vitalii-plagov-and-sam-stafford).

Answer (score 0):

I just create a new depot in the GUI and then add a new stream (again from GUI) make it a top level stream and then it asks if you want to branch an existing stream across. Select the depot/stream you need to fork and then it will copy that into your new stream.